# Why does right-clicking create an orange dot in the center of the circle?

Tags: python, kivy

Why does [the first widget example](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/firstwidget.html) in kivy lead to an orange circle in the middle of the yellow one when you right click on the canvas and a pure yellow one when you left click?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d/2, touch.y - d/2), size=(d, d))


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: This definitely freaked me out when I first saw it, had no idea why a Button would do that. Never worked with a touch-based library before.

Answer (score 39):

To disable multi-touch emulation, add this to your source file containing your main function, before any other kivy modules are imported:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
```

Comment: As far I can tell, it's not necessary to do this before other kivy modules are imported. I did your `Config.set[...]` command after all my imports and it worked fine.

Answer (score 15):

It's multitouch emulation, you can see how to disable it here

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.providers.mouse.html

Comment: (1) You can clear them by left clicking and re-setting a new simulated multi-touch. (2) You can set more than one. (3) Look at the Kivy examples/demo/pictures sample for a great example utilizing multi-touch emulation.

Comment: Link-only answers really aren't considered good practice (as you probably NOW know). Please summarize the contents in your answer.

Comment: This works on Windows, but causes problems on Android. Here's the exception I get if I try to open a DropDown sub class menu:     raise WidgetException(
[WARNING] stderr: kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <gui.customdropdown.CustomDropDown object at 0x7aaf231d60> to window, it already has a parent <kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7ab1290f40>