# Clicking on window with right click or scroll wheel adds red draggable circles in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I just started making a Kivy program which pretty much just opens a new black window on start. When I right click or click with a scroll wheel on the screen a draggable red circle is added. How can I disable this feature?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class HomeScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class AppController(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_controller = AppController()
    app_controller.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy is made to support multitouch devices too. Therefore it create those circles to tell us where the touch will be simulated and help us simulate multitouch.

See this answer to know how you can disable this: [why does right-clicking create an orange dot in the center of the circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692851/why-does-right-clicking-create-an-orange-dot-in-the-center-of-the-circle)

Or just go to : https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.providers.mouse.html