# Kivy: Remove the red dot creation on right clic

Tags: kivy, mouse

When creating a kivy exe on Windows with Pyinstaller, I still have the right click creating red dot.

[Why does right-clicking create an orange dot in the center of the circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692851/why-does-right-clicking-create-an-orange-dot-in-the-center-of-the-circle) proposed to use this to remove this behavior.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
```

But when I do, I can't scroll anymore on my page if I stay pressed on a widget.
Isn't there something more precise like `deactivate_red_dot`  rather than `deactivated_multitouch` which seems to have side effects ? Maybe a method of the `Mouse()` that we can override ?

Comment: I use `Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')`. Give that a try.

Comment: Didn't work as expected.

Comment: but thanks for the help, you helped me a lot of time already ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`venv/Lib/site_packages/kivy/input/providers/mouse.py`

Method `on_mouse_press`

Replace

```
do_graphics = (not self.disable_multitouch) and (
                button != 'left' or 'ctrl' in modifiers)
```

By
`do_graphics = False`

I'm not sure if I won't have others sides effects but that seems legit by the behavior I saw on the code.

EDIT:
Actually for my project, the bug with disable multitouchh was on android so I did:

```
if isWindows():
    from kivy.config import Config
    Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')
```

Good side, doesn't change fundamental library. Bad side, disabling multitouch could lead to others sneaky bugs.

Answer (score 0):

i did this to not disable my multitouch:

```
import kivy

# a modified copy of the original from github
def update_graphics(self, win, create=False):
    Color, Ellipse = (kivy.input.providers.mouse.Color, kivy.input.providers.mouse.Ellipse)
    de = self.ud.get('_drawelement', None)
    if de is None and create:
        if Color is None:
            from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
            kivy.input.providers.mouse.Color, kivy.input.providers.mouse.Ellipse = (Color, Ellipse)
    if de is not None:
        self.push()
        w, h = win._get_effective_size()
        self.scale_for_screen(w, h, rotation=win.rotation)
        de[1].pos = self.x - 10, self.y - 10
        self.pop()
kivy.input.providers.mouse.MouseMotionEvent.update_graphics = update_graphics
```

i simply cut the part with canvas and added 2 statement for Color and Ellipse to resolve for theyr nasty import with global variables.

i did not find any downside by now, let me now if you know or find one!